# How to inverse this equation which can give the devisors values of numbers

Tags: number-theory, inverse-function, distribution-of-primes

The roots of the following equation

$f(x) = sin^2(\pi*x) + sin^2(\pi*n/x)$

are the positive and negative devisor of ($n$)

For example, if we set ($n=7$) then ($x$) will have 4 real values {-7,-1,1,7}
and so for all prime numbers.

To make sure try to set integers to ($n$) and draw the equation.

Now the question is:

Is there any way to inverse this equation

$sin^2(\pi*x) + sin^2(\pi*n/x) = 0$

and find $x = f(n)$ by using Lambert W-function or any other technique?

If it is found then we can check the given number $n$ whether it is a prime or not by only calculating the equation real roots.

Comment: $a^2 +b^2=0$ Find out condition for $x$ any then you will get $n$.

Comment: Sometimes, in analytic number theory, a trick of this general nature can lead to very useful results. But I do not see a way to exploit your very nice observation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why? The OP wanted a relation between $x$ and $n$ . and I gave that in my answer. Have I done it wrong?

Comment: @Qwerty: My comment was intended for Nasser Dawood. Of course your explanation of why the result holds is correct. But the question seemed to be at least in large part about using the fact to produce a primality test, or more generally to factor $n$.

Comment: @Qwerty Indeed the explanations in your answer are most probably how the OP concocted their formula in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(\pi x)=0\implies x=\{k:k\in\Bbb{Z}\}$

$\sin(\pi n/x)=0\implies n/x=\{m:m\in\Bbb{Z}\}\implies n=\{xm:x,m\in\Bbb{Z}\}$